# How to add Badge to Android tablayout

Tags: android, xml, tabs, android-tablayout, badge

I want to add badge to my `TabLayout`.  When each add new element (item `ListView`) in database I want to show a Badge ( +1 ) in order to inform the user about each new.

Like this image :

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried, show your source code

Answer (score 3):

1. Design a `custom view` for each `TAB`.
2. Set `custom view` to each `TAB` by using TAB.setCustomView(custom_View)

**Try this:**

```
    // Tab
    Tab tab = YourTabLayout.getTabAt(position);

    // Get Custom view using LayoutInflater
    // ...........

    // Set custom view
    tab.setCustomView(custom_View);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a custom `View` to each tab.
so once you have your `ViewPager` and `Adapter` all set up.

Iterate over the tabs and add custom views.

something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
    tab.setCustomView(createCustomViewForTab(i);
}
```